# Active resource - load object from nested resource url

Tags: ruby, api, rest, activeresource

I'm writing a library to consume an API using Active Resource (4.0.0). The API returns nested resources as a URL, rather than an array of objects.

For instance, when I load a `Parent` object (an `ActiveResource::Base` descendant) using `Parent.find(1)`, I get a JSON response similar to:

```
"parent": {
  "username": "alex",
  "children": "http://domain.com/parents/alex/children"
}
```

Assuming I have another `ActiveResource::Base` subclass called `Children`, how can I access the children of this `Parent` object, as an array of `Children` instances created by requesting the provided children url? I'll get you started:

```
class Parent < ActiveResource::Base
  def children
    # HALP
    # (super returns the children url as a string)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `:from` parameter to `#find`:

```
class Parent < ActiveResource::Base
  # ...

  def children
    Child.find(:all, from: URI(super).path)
  end
end
```

However: it only allows you to change the path, not the complete URL. If the host part of the resource's URL might change, you have to change the resource's `site` also.